# What is the appropriate line length of bullet points?

Tags: design, information-architecture, typography, type

We can have information either in multiple paragraphs or a bullet point list. Visually, a bullet point is a paragraph with a black dot on the left.

We have two types of bullet point lists: Ordered and unordered.

When should we use bullet points and when should we use paragraphs? Is there any research on the ideal length for a bullet point item? Can it be as long as paragraph?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question you would need to look at two things in particular:

1. Best practice for bullet points
2. Optimal length of characters per line

Best practice would suggest that the purpose of a bullet point is to summarize or create an easily scannable list of items. The more you increase the length of the content in that bullet point item, the more you reduce the usefulness of the bullet point.

The second point is probably related to research about the appropriate average length of characters per line per screen, but I think a rule of thumb is around 75-100 characters (English) per line as an optimal length.

What would be the purpose of making a bullet point item a specific length? It should match the type of content you are presenting. Also, if you make the bullet point items as long as a paragraph, then what would be the purpose of using the different methods to present text?

Comment: Optimal line lengths are heavily dependent on other factors (typeface, type size, leading, context, page layout, etc.)

Comment: @DA01 That's true. I guess there are two components to the optimal line length, one being the amount of information/content, and the other being how it is presented.

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule here. In general, though, if you're writing paragraphs, then you're likely not 'getting to the point' as fast as typically warranted via a bulleted list.

As for when to use ordered vs. unordered, that's a bit easier: is there a particular order to the points? Then consider ordered.